# Multiple static IPs Amazon EC2

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, amazon-ec2, ssl, amazon-web-services

I want to have multiple sites with SSL on IIS (Windows 2008 R2 on Amazon AWS).

I've read [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17609389/multiple-ssl-certificates-for-different-domain-on-iis-amazon-ec2) and the [documentation in Amazon](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/config-windows-multiple-ip.html) where it explains how to add another IP.

My question is, since I'm setting what used to be a DHCP assigned IP to be static.

What's going to happen for example to an AMI created with a static IP?  Am I going to be able to start it?  What's going to happen if I turn off the computer and start it again or if Amazon decides to change the way they assign their IPs?

Comment: Are you trying to set up public web sites or internal web sites? This will not help you with public web sites.

Comment: @MichaelHampton 2 (or more) public sites.  I saw the documentation is for VPC, that means that I cannot access to them even if I assign 2 elastic IPs?  (Never used VPC yet).  Thanks

Comment: You ought to just use SNI and don't worry about extra public IP addresses. This is trivial to set up; just make sure the option is ticked in the IIS site binding.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelHampton.  I didn't know about SNI. If you put that as an answer I'll mark it as answered.  Thank you again!